# How to handle mousepressed event along action command

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How to move to various `JFrame` with handling mousepressed event along action command and get action command. Java swing code:

```
//this code belongs to home jframe class

mntmPublicSector= new JMenuItem("Public Sector");
    mntmPublicSector.setActionCommand("public");
    mntmPublicSector.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) { int select=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"if already user login","not user Register now",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(select==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                new Login_Page().setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                new Student_Register().setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            } }});

mntmStateSector = new JMenuItem("State Sector");
    mntmStateSector.setActionCommand("state");
    mntmStateSector.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) { int select=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"if already user login","not user Register now",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(select==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                new Login_Page().setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                new Student_Register().setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            } }});



mntmApptitude = new JMenuItem("Apptitude");
     mntmApptitude.setActionCommand("app");
    mntmApptitude.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) { int select=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"if already user login","not user Register now",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(select==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                new Login_Page().setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                new Student_Register().setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            } }});



/*if i click with if i login,it needs to take to respective jframe [--App_Exam_Register_Panel()--or --State_exam_reg()-- or -- Public_exam_Reg()-- ] */

//this code belongs to login jframe class    
JButton btnLogin = new JButton(iim);
Home hm=new Home();
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {             
            String st=hm.mntmPublicSector.getActionCommand();
            String st1 =hm.mntmStateSector.getActionCommand();
            String aps=hm.mntmApptitude.getActionCommand();
            //String apss=hm.mntmApptitude
            if(st.equals("public"))
            {
                new Public_exam_Reg().setVisible(true);//jframe class
                dispose();
            }     //switch case
            else if(st1.equals("state"))
            {
                new State_exam_reg().setVisible(true);//jframe class
                dispose();
            }
            else if (aps.equals("Apptitude"))
            {
            new App_Exam_Register_Panel().setVisible(true);//jframe class
                dispose();
            }       }       });
```

Comment: am new to stackoverflow ,

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe and the result you expect.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a MouseListener on a JMenuItem.

To handle the click of the menu item you should be using an Action.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more information and working examples.

Keep a link to the tutorial handle for examples of other Swing basics.